# Co-occurrence graph RpcTimeoutException in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file that maps from documentId to entities and I extract document co-occurrences. The entities RDD looks like this:

```
//documentId -> (name, type, frequency per document)
val docEntityTupleRDD: RDD[(Int, Iterable[(String, String, Int)])]
```

To extract relationships between entities and their frequency within each document, I use the following code:

```
def hashId(str: String) = {
    Hashing.md5().hashString(str, Charsets.UTF_8).asLong()
}

val docRelTupleRDD = docEntityTupleRDD
  //flatMap at SampleGraph.scala:62
  .flatMap { case(docId, entities) =>
    val entitiesWithId = entities.map { case(name, _, freq) => (hashId(name), freq) }.toList
    val relationships = entitiesWithId.combinations(2).collect {
      case Seq((id1, freq1), (id2, freq2)) if id1 != id2 =>
        // Make sure left side is less than right side
        val (first, second) = if (id1 < id2) (id1, id2) else (id2, id1)
        ((first, second), (docId.toInt, freq1 * freq2))
    }
    relationships
  }


val zero = collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
val edges: RDD[Edge[immutable.Map[Int, Int]]] = docRelTupleRDD
  .aggregateByKey(zero)(
    (map, v) => map += v,
    (map1, map2) => map1 ++= map2
  )
  .map { case ((e1, e2), freqMap) => Edge(e1, e2, freqMap.toMap) }
```

Each edge stores the relationship frequency per document in a Map. When I'm trying to write the edges to file:

```
edges.saveAsTextFile(outputFile + "_edges")
```

I receive the following errors after some time:

```
15/12/28 02:39:40 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 127198 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
15/12/28 02:39:40 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after 127198 ms
15/12/28 02:39:40 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for driver from TaskSet 0.0
15/12/28 02:42:50 WARN AkkaRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@64c6e4c4,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 35375))] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
15/12/28 02:42:50 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)
15/12/28 02:43:55 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/12/28 02:46:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)
[...]
15/12/28 02:47:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
15/12/28 02:48:36 WARN AkkaRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@64c6e4c4,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 35375))] in 2 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
15/12/28 02:49:39 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/12/28 02:49:39 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (flatMap at SampleGraph.scala:62) failed in 3321.145 s
15/12/28 02:51:06 WARN SparkContext: Killing executors is only supported in coarse-grained mode
[...]
```

My spark configuration looks like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .setAppName("wordCount")
  .setMaster("local[8]")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
  .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g")
  // Increase memory fraction to prevent disk spilling
  .set("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", "0.3")
  // Disable spilling
  // If set to "true", limits the amount of memory used during reduces by spilling data out to disk.
  // This spilling threshold is specified by spark.shuffle.memoryFraction.
  .set("spark.shuffle.spill", "false")
```

I already increased the executor memory and refactored a previous `reduceByKey` construct with `aggregateByKey` after [research](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/) on the internet. Error stays the same. Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, obviously your code is O(N^2) for each document. So the first thing you can try is to increase a number of partitions proportionally to the average document size. I would be careful with `spark.shuffle.spill`.  If output is to large to fit into memory data go to disk anyway but in a less optimal conditions. Also ` if (id1 < id2)` check is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've followed your suggestion and increased the partitions i.e. `aggregateByKey(zero, numPartitions = 44)`. Still the same exception. Do you mean entities per document by "document size" or number of documents? This makes a judge difference in my case. I've also studied this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/). They suggest to multiplying the number of partitions in the parent RDD (`docRelTupleRDD.partitions.size` -> 13) by 1.5. Not sure, if 44 partitions is still to less. Why is `id1<id2` obsolete?

Comment: `aggregateByKey` is far to late. You want this before you even `flatMap`. How many partitions you have initially (and how much data )? What is the average size of `Iterable[(String, String, Int)]`? It is obsolete because it is already covered by `combinations`.